# Finding an accurate distribution to my data of large sample of the sum of daily rainfall at a specific location

Tags: r, gamma-distribution, fitting

I have a rather large sample of the sum of daily rainfall at a specific location in mm. I am currently attempting to find the best fitting distribution using the `fitdistr()` function in MASS. Some graphical comparisons between my data and general distribution functions lead me to believe that a gamma distribution would be a good fit.

My first thought was to simply try:

```
fitdistr(rainfall$values, "gamma")
```

resulting in the following error :

```
Error in stats::optim(x = c(1.4, 1.6, 1.7, 0, 1.3, 9, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

Then I tried to give the function a list of various starting parameters as specified in the documentation, like so:

```
fitdistr(rainfall$values,"gamma", start = list(shape=0,rate=1))
```

giving me another error:

```
Error in stats::optim(x = c(1.4, 1.6, 1.7, 0, 1.3, 9, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [1]
```

I suspect that the problem is the rather large amount of values that equal 0 (on days without rainfall).

Is there a way to fit the distribution to my data?

I may have found a work-around to my problem by simply adding 0.00001 to every value, thereby eliminating every 0 in my dataset. But I am unsure if this "fix" is a statistically sound way of solving things and not just bad practice.

If you are aware of any distributions that lend themselves to daily precipitation data, it would be appreciated.

Comment: The support of the gamma distribution is on the *positive* reals, so no zeros. Adding a small number to each value is one way. Another is a mixture model with a third parameter representing the probability of observing `0`. So inference on the gamma parameters depends only on the non-zero values.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So assuming a gamma distribution based on my altered data (since it has the best fit) isnt problematic and i could use that dataset for i.e. a GLM?

Comment: As for appropriateness, further literature search might be helpful. A quick search suggests zero-inflated gamma models are common: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jps/2018/1012647/ or https://dept.atmos.ucla.edu/sites/default/files/cristian_martinez_villalobos/files/jas-d-18-0343.1.pdf

Comment: Why are you interested in fitting a distribution? You have zero-inflated data, which means you have a binomial distribution for precipitation / no-precipitation and another distribution (possibly gamma) for the amount of precipitation if there is precipitation.